# How to add checkbox as column header in grid control dotnetbar winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbar

I'm a beginner with DotNetBar(devComponents). I'm using a gridControl which needs to have a checkbox as column header. If I select that checkbox all checkboxes under the column would need to get selected, and vice versa. 
I googled for this, but unable to get this.

Is it possible to do this.? If so, please guide me to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could get an answer to your question by asking it on DotNetBar forum:

https://www.devcomponents.com/customeronly/forum/default.asp